# Thunderbird 60 Manjaro (arch) tray

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, thunderbird, tray

I use Manjaro (arch) and Thunderbird 60.4.0.
Are there any add-ons or apps to show Thunderbird in tray (and unread message count)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use birdtray:
    Birdtray — Birdtray is a system tray new mail notification for Thunderbird 60+ which does not require extensions. Run Thunderbird with a system tray icon.

```
https://github.com/gyunaev/birdtray || birdtrayAUR
```

it is already on aur.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *alltray* together with a thunderbird addon called *Keep in Taskbar* by Tinnyx.
First install the add-on using thunderbirds add-on section.
Then install alltray with `pacman -S alltray` then add `alltray -H thunderbird` to system startup commands.

This will launch Thunderbird at system startup minimized in tray.
(It will not show message count though.)

You can leave `-H` out if you don't want to start minimized.

Alltray is supposed to work on any program so it's quite a useful tool. It definitely works on Thunderbird after version 60. It didn't play very well with Thunderbird up to version 60.